# How to enable thread-safe access to a collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp, thread-safety, observablecollection

When an `ObservebleCollection<T>` is bound to a UI control, it is very hard to add items to (or remove items from) the collection if it is used on multiple threads.

In order to avoid this problem, `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` is available to WPF, and so is `BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization` to Xamarin.Forms.

Is there an equivalent of these useful methods in UWP? If not, how is it possible to enable thread-safe access to `ObservebleCollection<T>` that is bound to UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such method that could synchronized access to a collection that is used on multiple threads within UWP platform. You can only update a data-bound ObservableCollection in the [dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-18362) thread.

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
  // Update  ObservableCollection
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Is it necessary to lock the `ObservableCollection` in the `Dispatcher.RunAsync` method?

Comment: Yep, if you update ObservableCollection  in `Task.Run(()=>{})`  non-ui thread, it will throw exception, and the ui will not change.

Comment: And if the current thread is ui- thread, we have no need call Dispatcher again. for example Button Click event.